# How to get only one row against each id in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables:

**Table1**:

```
ID       Date1
----------------------------
G-1      2018-08-01 23:04:15
G-2      2018-08-02 18:07:22
```

**Table2**

```
ID       Date2                   Remarks
-------------------------------------------
G-1      2018-08-01 23:45:45     Rgt RTT
G-1      2018-08-02 19:07:18     AFF XTX
G-1      2018-08-02 21:25:45     Accepted
G-2      2018-08-03 15:03:04     Ref ytt
G-3      2018-08-04 18:07:07     Accepted
G-4      2018-08-05 22:25:45     Accepted
```

I want output like (Row where `Remarks` is `Accepted` in Table2, oldest one based on `Date2`):

```
ID       Date1                 Date2                   Remarks  
----------------------------------------------------------------
G-1      2018-08-01 23:04:15   2018-08-02 21:25:45     Accepted
G-2      2018-08-02 18:07:22   2018-08-04 18:07:07     Accepted
```

But when I am using this query, I get back all the data with remarks by join:

```
select 
    t1.ID, t1.Date1, t2.Date2, t2.Remarks 
from
    Table1
Left join 
    Table2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
where 
    t2.Remarks = 'Accepted';
```

Comment: `G-2      2018-08-02 18:07:22   2018-08-04 18:07:07     Accepted` is this a correct out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use aggregate `min,max` function , as you said you want min in date2 so i changed

```
select t1.ID, min(t1.Date1) as date1 ,min(t2.Date2) as date2 ,t2.Remarks from
Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID
where t2.Remarks='Accepted'
group by t1.ID,t2.Remarks
```

Comment: Date2 would be `Min`, if i want to get the oldest value??

Comment: Getting error `column "t1.Date1" must appear in the Group By clause or be used in an aggregate function;`

Comment: please use my answer cause i already t.date1 into aggregate function @Jupiter

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select t1.id, t1.date, t2.date, t2.remarks
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t2.id = t1.id
where t2.remarks = 'Accepted' and
      t2.date = (select min(tt2.date)
                 from table2 tt2
                 where tt2.id = t2.id and tt2.remarks = 'Accepted'
                );
```

Answer (score -1):

just add group by and min to your query

```
min (date)
group by t1.ID
```